# What are the RPC approaches for .NET 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, client-server, rpc

I am writing a Client/Server application need to communicate with each other via RPC.

I know .NET remoting as a beginner. If there is/are another alternative, please tell me.

Comment: Take a look at WCF http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wcf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WCF Duplex is way to go http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Read up on [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324) (Windows Communication Framework) and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Astn/JSON-RPC.NET

JSON-RPC.Net is a high-performance JSON-Rpc 2.0 server, leveraging the popular JSON.NET library. Host in ASP.NET, also supports sockets and pipes,

Requirements

dotnet 4.0 or mono